# How to use GetMessage with SetWindowsHookEx and have it return early

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing a Windows c++ application, and currently running into issue with GetMessage, below is my simple program, which intercepts keyboard inputs to all programs.

```
LRESULT WINAPI keyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    printf("Hey!\n");
    return 1;
    //return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)(keyboardProc), NULL, 0);
    MSG message;
    memset(&message, 0, sizeof(MSG));

    GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0);

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that GetMessage never returns. I cannot use PeekMessage because to use PeekMessage I need to add a Sleep function in the message loop, which slows down the hook significantly (with Sleep(1), you can notice a lot of lag when scanning barcodes), but without Sleep(1), the loop will consume a ton of CPU.

Since keyboard events does not cause GetMessage to return early, how can I cause GetMessage to return early? (For example perhaps posting a WM_USER / WM_QUIT message from another thread? I've tried different options to no avail and the documentation is quite confusing) I'm new to this so code example to show the following would be much appreciated:

1. listen to user input in the same / different thread via cin.get()
2. Once cin.get() returns, the program will cause GetMessage to return early

Comment: _"Since keyboard events does not cause GetMessage to return early, how can I cause GetMessage to return early?"_ - What is you main objective? Why is `GetMessage` involved in this objective?

Comment: Sidenote: Don't cast unless necessary. Remove `(HOOKPROC)`. If your function has the wrong signature, you _want_ it to fail compiling.

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is. At a guess, you want a `MessageBox()` in place of the `GetMessage()` call.

Comment: Without GetMessage keyboardProc won't receive any events. I do not want a MessageBox in place of GetMessage.

Comment: Correct, but that doesn't necessarily mean that *you* have to call `GetMessage()`. The call to `GetMessage()` from `MessageBox()` works just as well and provides users with a way to terminate the program with no additional code.

Comment: See accepted answer which solved the problem. What happens if the program were to run without an UI? Or it uses a UI library like QT.

Comment: *"What happens if the program were to run without an UI?"* - Nothing. It just doesn't have a UI. Which is a rather user-hostile design for something as highly invasive as a low-level hook. *"Or it uses a UI library like QT."* - Things don't change. As I explained earlier, there is no requirement for *you*, specifically, to call a message retrieval function. Qt does that already, so you don't have to do anything extra to have your low-level hook execute its callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetMessage` only returns when a message is posted to your application, not when the hook is triggered.

first, you need to decide when you are going to quit, then post a `WM_QUIT` (or any message) to your main thread, or the thread that installed the hook.

you can call [PostThreadMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagea) from any thread and pass the stored main thread id to post a message to your main thread, the following code does that when the user presses `x`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

HHOOK g_hookHandle = nullptr;
DWORD g_mainThreadId = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pKeyboardData = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
        DWORD vkCode = pKeyboardData->vkCode;

        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            if (vkCode == 'X')  // quit when button is X
            {
                std::cout << "Exiting the program." << std::endl;

                PostThreadMessage(g_mainThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0 ,0); // post WM_QUIT to end app
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(g_hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    g_hookHandle = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHookProc, nullptr, 0);
    g_mainThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();  // to send a message to it later
    MSG message;
    GetMessage(&message, nullptr, 0, 0);

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hookHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `GetMessage()` doesn't return when a message is sent. It returns exclusively when messages are *posted* (or synthesized).

Comment: @IInspectable you are correct, i use the word send to mean both `SendMessage` or `PostMessage`, the correct terminology is indeed `Post`, i corrected that.

Comment: This worked, by GetCurrentThreadId(), saving it to a shared variable, then PostThreadMessage will successfully cause GetMessage to return.

Comment: The hook procedure is called on the same thread that installed the hook. There's no need to capture the current thread's ID in a global variable. You can call `GetCurrentThreadId()` from the hook procedure. Posting a (fake) `WM_QUIT` message is usually [wrong](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453).

Comment: @IInspectable it is written that way so it could be moved to another thread, since that was clearly the OP's intention.

Comment: You cannot move *"it"* to another thread, regardless of what *"it"* is. The rules are fixed: `SetWindowsHookExW()` requires that the calling thread calls one of the message retrieval functions. Those functions internally call into the hook procedure. The hook procedure is called on the same thread that called the message retrieval function (which, by induction, is the same thread that installed the hook). All of that is executed on the same thread.

Comment: I used PostThreadMessage from another thread (UI thread) rather than within the hook function.

Comment: @ZhuMengxi Why don't you send a message to a message-only window then? That's what they are for.